# Magento2: Carrier.php file

Tags: magento2, shipping-methods, custom-shipping-method

I want to create custom shipping module in Magento2. For that I need to create carrier.php.
Which steps should I follow while creating Carrier.php?
Help would be appreciated.:)

Comment: Please refer http://inchoo.net/magento-2/creating-a-shipping-method-in-magento-2/

Answer (score 3):

You can create sample shipping module using below link.

http://cedcommerce.com/magento-2-module-creator/shipping-module

Then you can customize it as per need.

**EDIT**

For custom carrier you can create like following code.

**Customshipping.php**

```
<?php
namespace Vendor\Module\Model\Carrier;
use Magento\Framework\App\Config\ScopeConfigInterface;
use Magento\Framework\DataObject;
use Magento\Shipping\Model\Carrier\AbstractCarrier;
use Magento\Shipping\Model\Carrier\CarrierInterface;
use Magento\Shipping\Model\Config;
use Magento\Shipping\Model\Rate\ResultFactory;
use Magento\Store\Model\ScopeInterface;
use Magento\Quote\Model\Quote\Address\RateResult\ErrorFactory;
use Magento\Quote\Model\Quote\Address\RateResult\Method;
use Magento\Quote\Model\Quote\Address\RateResult\MethodFactory;
use Magento\Quote\Model\Quote\Address\RateRequest;
use Psr\Log\LoggerInterface;

class Customshipping extends AbstractCarrier implements CarrierInterface
{
    /**
     * Carrier's code
     *
     * @var string
     */
    protected $_code = 'mycustomshipping';
    /**
     * Whether this carrier has fixed rates calculation
     *
     * @var bool
     */
    protected $_isFixed = true;
    /**
     * @var ResultFactory
     */
    protected $_rateResultFactory;
    /**
     * @var MethodFactory
     */
    protected $_rateMethodFactory;
    /**
     * @param ScopeConfigInterface $scopeConfig
     * @param ErrorFactory $rateErrorFactory
     * @param LoggerInterface $logger
     * @param ResultFactory $rateResultFactory
     * @param MethodFactory $rateMethodFactory
     * @param array $data
     */
    public function __construct(
        ScopeConfigInterface $scopeConfig,
        ErrorFactory $rateErrorFactory,
        LoggerInterface $logger,
        ResultFactory $rateResultFactory,
        MethodFactory $rateMethodFactory,
        array $data = []
    ) {
        $this->_rateResultFactory = $rateResultFactory;
        $this->_rateMethodFactory = $rateMethodFactory;
        parent::__construct($scopeConfig, $rateErrorFactory, $logger, $data);
    }
    /**
     * Generates list of allowed carrier`s shipping methods
     * Displays on cart price rules page
     *
     * @return array
     * @api
     */
    public function getAllowedMethods()
    {
        return [$this->getCarrierCode() => __($this->getConfigData('name'))];
    }
    /**
     * Collect and get rates for storefront
     *
     * @SuppressWarnings(PHPMD.UnusedFormalParameter)
     * @param RateRequest $request
     * @return DataObject|bool|null
     * @api
     */
    public function collectRates(RateRequest $request)
    {
        /**
         * Make sure that Shipping method is enabled
         */
        if (!$this->isActive()) {
            return false;
        }
        /** @var \Magento\Shipping\Model\Rate\Result $result */
        $result = $this->_rateResultFactory->create();
        $shippingPrice = $this->getConfigData('price');
        $method = $this->_rateMethodFactory->create();
        /**
         * Set carrier's method data
         */
        $method->setCarrier($this->getCarrierCode());
        $method->setCarrierTitle($this->getConfigData('title'));
        /**
         * Displayed as shipping method under Carrier
         */
        $method->setMethod($this->getCarrierCode());
        $method->setMethodTitle($this->getConfigData('name'));
        $method->setPrice($shippingPrice);
        $method->setCost($shippingPrice);
        $result->append($method);
        return $result;
    }
}
```

Comment: thanks for this amazing basic module !! Can you let me know the correct approach to start connecting the module to any external web service (like Fedex/ParcelForce etc.)?

Comment: @Krishan thanks for basic module guidance. I have created basic module now I want to configure carrier.php which steps should follow?

Comment: For carrier example, I updated answer. Please check.

Comment: Thank you @Krishan. Can you explain some functionalities so that I can configure additional ones?

Comment: Which functionalities ?